# 2002 Toyota RAV4 Stripped PCV Valve Threads on Valve Cover

Tags: toyota, rav4, pcv-valve

Stripped PCV valve threads on valve cover while removing old PCV valve; however, new PCV valve wiggles but does not fall out, even with tugging. Also, short and long term fuel trims at idle have not changed (i.e., gotten worse) with new but loose PCV valve.

I assume the best and most expensive repair solution is to replace the valve cover and gasket.

Looking for comments on the wisdom and risk of an alternate cheaper solution of removing valve cover to do stripped thread repair and replace gasket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of to "fix" this without replacing the valve cover:

1. Use a piece of thin rubber, or build up some teflon tape around the threads. The idea here is to just seal the threads so you are sucking out the bad gasses from the crankcase and not just pulling air from past the threads. It won't actually fix the bad threads, but it creates enough of an interference to close the gap and seal it up.
2. Use some JB Weld or some other type of thread maker compound. This will "fix" the threads themselves and save you the hassle of replacing the valve cover.